# Его проводили в комнату: просторную, уютную и чистую - что лучше использовать двоеточие или запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие

В предложении "Алексея проводили в его комнату: просторную, уютную и всегда безукоризненно чистую" что уместнее использовать, запятую или двоеточие?

Comment: Ещё тире можно использовать. В вопрос можно третий вариант добавить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из перечисленных знаков препинания - запятую, но здесь более уместно тире.

В справочнике Лопатина читаем:

> Определения, стоящие в конце предложения, как нераспространенные, так
>   и с зависимыми словами, могут отделяться знаком тире. Такие
>   определения имеют пояснительно-уточняющее значение: От результатов
>   этой борьбы зависит, в конечном счете, человеческое счастье —
>   настоящее и будущее(Аст.); Затем я снова замечал ее взгляды на себе —
>   то пытливый и проницательный, вызывающий тревогу, то отсутсутвующий, с
>   потерянной мыслью, то быстрый, настороженно лукавый (Расп.); И пришла
>   весна — добрая и бестолковая (Шукш.); Опять пахло дымом, но только это
>   был иной запах — древесный, сухой, утренний (Шукш.).

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=117

*Алексея проводили в его комнату - просторную, уютную и всегда безукоризненно чистую*". Пояснительно-уточняющее значение подчёркивается позицией в конце предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Двоеточие при перечислениях обычно ставиться, когда есть общее слово (род) и частные элементы этого целого (виды).

Грубый пример, но даёт понять суть:

`Его проводили в комнату с такими особенностями: просторная, уютная и безукоризненно чистая.`

Простой пример:

`Он любит такие фрукты: бананы, апельсины и яблоки.`

Данные однородные элементы в конце предложения не являются видами комнаты, а являются определением её свойств. В таких случаях можно поставить тире или запятую.

При обширных существенных определениях, особенно в конце предложения, лучше ставить тире.

При маленьких несущественных определениях, особенно в середине предложения, лучше ставить запятую (уточнение).

Очевидный вывод: лучше всего тире.